# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am using nodejs and socket.io

This is my js code for the button.

```
$(document).on("click", ".actionInvite", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
    getUid = $(this).closest('.wrap_body').find("input[name='hiddenuid']").val();
    getConference = $("select[name='subuid'] option:selected").val();
    var uid = $(this).closest('.wrap_body').find("input[name='hiddenuid']").val();
    var action = "originate";
    var conference = $("select[name='subuid'] option:selected").val();
    var data = {
        "action": "originate",
        "sid": uid,
        "conference": conference
    }
    socket.emit("action", data);
    $("#" + uid).find(".actionInvite").hide();
    $("#" + uid).find(".inviteX").show();
    $("." + uid).find(".actionInvite").hide();
    $("." + uid).find(".inviteX").show();
    alert("Call: " + uid + "?");
});
```

When i dont reload the page for about **20 minutes** or so and i click the **button**  i got this error on my console.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .

But when i reload it again . And click again the **button** . It is ok again..

the error code is at line 2 of **jquery.min.js**

sorry the code is to long. i cant post it

What is the possible problem?

Comment: at what line can you show what is the linenumber and what is the code creating this issue?

Comment: may be your socket connection is getting timed out during that period.

Comment: getUid,getConference global variable? Also var uid is same as getUid?

Comment: yes @user2181397 they are global variable.